# Merge unallocated space to extended partition and create new logical drive

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I am new to Ubuntu. I just formatted, and installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. While partitioning, I made a mistake it seems.  20 GB goes unallocated and I am unable to use it. I used Gparted to try to recover that space. I already tried many existing solutions, but it is not working for me. I hope my question is clear.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What kind of solutions? Also, have you tried formatting the unallocated space and thex extending it?

Comment: If I try to create a new partition with unallocated (last one in screen shot) it says you cannot create more than 4 primary partitions.  I tried as much in windows also.  That doesn't help me.

Comment: That's a bummer. One of the downsides when buying a computer is that Windows will take 3 of the primary partitions where as Ubuntu only needs 1 (which can have many logical partitions). Stock computers do not come with a Windows Recovery CD anymore because it is stored in your HDD as the Recovery Partition. Windows needs 2 primary partitions to work. An option is to remove the recovery partition but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out how to do it.
Just boot to ubuntu from live boot cd/usb.
gparted will be there already.  Just open it.
Then right click swap area and do swap off.
Next, right click the extended partition and then select resize.  Resize the extended partition.
Then commit your changes.
Right click the extended partition then, switch the swap on.

Thats it.  My extended partition is now merged with extended one.

Comment: Thank you sir, I was going to ask a similar question, but then I found this one. I actually wanted to do the opposite, move unallocated space out of a partition, not move more space into it, but the `Swapoff` and `Swapon` procedure also worked for that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to grow the extended partition till it assimilates the unused capacity, then you will be able to format. It needs to be within the boundary of the extended, as you can only have 4 MBR partitions or 3 + 1 extended with 5 or more partitions being within/part of the extended partition itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use gparted and resize the extended partition, then you can either resize your logical partition or create another one as fleamour says.